# Use each value in a list to filter for subsets?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, iteration

I have a large data set that I need to create several subsets for. I want to take each string value in the list to filter a column on the larger data set and save as a subset. So for each value in the `unique` list, I need to filter `full_df` and save as a subset.

Will this require some kind of function, iteration, or loop? All help solving this is appreciated.

```
unique = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']

aba = full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == "aba")
xyz = full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == "xyz")
xgx = full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == "xgx")
dssd = full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == "dssd")
sdjh = full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == "sdjh")
```

Comment: Use a `dict` - for example: `myDataFrames = {key: full_df.loc[(full_df['filter'] == key)] for key in unique}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
d_df =  {}

unique = ['aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh']

for i in unique:
   d_df[i] = full_df.loc[full_df['filter'] == i]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea seems right, just loop over the values for the subsets.

```
unique = ('aba', 'xyz', 'xgx', 'dssd', 'sdjh')
subset_dfs = {}

for unique_key in unique:
    subset_dfs[unique_key] = full_df.loc[full_df['filter'] == unique_key]
```